# Repopulating PostgreSQL database with data directory from another database Instance

Tags: postgresql

I have had to delete PostgreSQL for an issue and reinstall it, however before uninstalling I did not execute the command pg_dump. I still have the data directory from this instance. After reinstalling PostgreSQL, I receive all the same tables and schemas from my prior database, but not the same data. The data directories are two separate, but I want to combine the previous data directory into the new one. How would I go about such a process, if possible?

Answer (score 0):

#### Assumptions

I'm assuming you have two instances each one with a different data directory but with the same schema for the same version of postgres installed.
I'm also assuming when the server starts is using your newly created, possibly empty, instance

#### What to do

You should try to start a new instance of the server pointing to your backup data directory...
Somenthing like

```
pg_ctl -D /path/to/backup/dir -l /path/to/log start -o "-p 5433"
```

If this works, your backup instance is running on port 5433.
Check if everything is in place and the data is consistent.

If so then you could simply make arrangements for your server to always start pointing to your backup directory and safely delete your newly created data directory.

Comment: I appreciate your advice, and I apologize for the late response. What had happened was there was an issue with my first installation of postgresql, and I was in a bind; I uninstalled (left the data directory alone and did not perform a dump) and reinstalled with postgres.app. I have not tried your method yet, but it seems to me that in your assumption, you assume that I still have old instance available; to which I unfortunately do not. Please do tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: For this you just need the old data directory. Whether your new installed postgresql is running an instance or not is not important because you will manually start a new one in a different port (5433) with a different data directory (your old data directory) which is supposed to be valid because it was created with the same version of postgresql in a previous install. Try the command and see if that works. Please make a backup of your backup just in case ;)

Comment: When using this command, I get invalid option --1

Comment: When dropping the /path/to/log, I get the server started -- however, when trying to access using pgadmin III I cannot connect to server

Comment: The error is : `psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory. Is the server running locally and accepting conections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5433"?

Comment: That is not a `1` (one). It's an `l` (letter l). Re run the command and check the log for new info. That message is telling you that the server never started or is not listening on that port, which is strange because the `-o` flag. Consider using `-w` flag to wait for startup to complete. Also check for the process using `ps -ef | grep postgres`. Other useful info: What SO is your server running? How do you normally start postgres? as a service? via `pg_ctl`? Who owns your _old_ data directory?

Comment: Okay, I have gotten this to work. Now, I am trying to restore new database (which has the same schema, tables, etc.. just no data). When restoring the database, I receive this error:
`/Applications/pgAdmin3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/pg_restore --host localhost -- port 5432 -- username "postgres" --dbname "postgres" --role "postgres" --no-password --format directory --verbose "/Library/Postgres/9.5/data" 
pg_restore: [directory archiver] could not open input file "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/data/toc.dat": No such file or directory`

Comment: I am using pgadmin III

Comment: What exactly means _I have gotten this to work_ ? You cannot restore from that directory because there is no backup taken with `pg_dump`. You can only start the server using that directory and the take the backup to restore. My answer tries to do that. Do you have access to console and/or root account?

Comment: Ahh, I now understand fully the method. I moved the data directory of new database to old, and I was able to start a server with the old data directory. However, I am yet to open this new server in pgadmin and make a back up. I do have access to both console and root account

Comment: It looks like you are on the right track. Why not replace your new directory with the backup and just start the server. It'll be with your original data. No need to `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`. No need to change anything on your pgAdmin III configuration.

Comment: Okay, I have tried that and restarted the server. However, when connecting to the server I am told that the serve isn't listening. I am using pg_ctl to start the server. In my log I am given : invalid IP mask "trust": nodename nor servname provided, or not known. Could not load pg_hba.conf. I understand the error, but I do not know why it is happening; as it neer happened with previous directory.

Comment: Also, I am told that postmaster.pid does not exist